# React native firebase crashes when using emulator

Tags: javascript, java, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm struggling for a few days now on using **firestore emulator** in a react-native project

Whenever the code reaches a firestore hit the application crash without any log (RN side).
Now I know RNFirebase is well installed as I can hit firestore real server.
I've checked the logcat and it gives me this error.

```
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.test_project, PID: 6383
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (23.0.4).
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3(AsyncQueue.java:537)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$jx84dqgUsF4ojecSMurRqFLFD1Y.run(Unknown Source:2)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot find a NameResolver for http://localhost:5003
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.getResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.0:15)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.FirestoreChannel.lambda$runBidiStreamingRpc$0$FirestoreChannel(FirestoreChannel.java:109)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.-$$Lambda$FirestoreChannel$ThFui-hvcsrVGYxlBtcTH5vVbvE.onComplete(Unknown Source:6)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.0:4)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:232)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot find a NameResolver for http://localhost:5003
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.getNameResolver(ManagedChannelImpl.java:729)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.<init>(ManagedChannelImpl.java:609)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:518)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.grpc.android.AndroidChannelBuilder.build(AndroidChannelBuilder.java:149)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.initChannel(GrpcCallProvider.java:130)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.lambda$initChannelTask$6$GrpcCallProvider(GrpcCallProvider.java:256)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.-$$Lambda$GrpcCallProvider$SCD5iiibQ8l4haiO8ofSfE0wIJg.call(Unknown Source:2)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzy.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.0:2)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0$ThrottledForwardingExecutor(ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java:54)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$ThrottledForwardingExecutor$MfIJbVuxZtLwosAgPzPA-cU66Ko.run(Unknown Source:4)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
10-23 11:07:22.925  6383  6383 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 1 more
```

Here is my packages.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.9.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^12.9.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^12.9.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.1"
  }
```

And I have firebase-tools v9.21.0

Here is a simple code that I used to debug my problem:
https://gist.github.com/jeremytrips/8cc29f7611fa34bc3cd9f7fd1157f1c0.

I'm completely lost as I don't know a thing in Java.
Any help would really be appreciated.
Thanks in advance 
Jeremy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase team has concluded about this error in a [Github thread](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/4699#issuecomment-749682263):

> [T]his is an error in the underlying SDK and you should try to
> reproduce it and log it in the [underlying repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues)
> using the
> [appropriate quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/firestore).
>
> For a workaround, on the Android emulator you can't reach the local
> network normally. You can reach the host machine via a special IP
> address normally, with no extra steps. Any other use of the network
> external to the emulator requires adb forwards normally so that it
> appears to the emulator that it is connecting to the emulator host but
> the connection actually forwards out somewhere else. SSH port
> forwarding may be used also in order to bind some remote service to
> your local machine so the emulator may get it. In the end you will
> then have the emulator connecting to `localhost` or `10.0.2.2` (the
> special emulator address for emulator host) and it should work.
>
> That is all project and network specific, there is no way we can
> foresee all setups. You can google for **adb network forwarding**, or you
> can run the emulator on the emulator's host machine (the normal
> scenario).

You can try using the workaround in order to reach the host machine.